# Remove item from cart return to home page issue magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, ce-1.9.2.4

We're using Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 and we have an issue where a user removes an item from the cart and the cart will redirect back to the homepage instead of conventionally just returning to the checkout page (even with zero items).

Comment: Are you using any custom checkout module? How the link looks to removing the item? What's happening in network console - is there a redirect, what's the response to POST?

Comment: I am using porto theme and there is a  **X** icon to remove item. When i remove any item from cart i'll redirected to home page of my site.